# Why isn't html running javascript I import when I use import-export

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

My code works fine when I add my module straight into the html code, but it won't load it when I try to first import the module to a different javascript file.

I've tried exporting everything, from my module.

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello world
        </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Tradingpost, done by no css gang.</h1>

        <div id="sidenav">Here be the links to other pages</div>

        <br>

        <footer id="footer">
            Done whenever. Copyright is mine.
        </footer>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
import * as sidebar from "./visualModules/sidebarmodule"

function cumulator() {
    sidebar.createSidebar()
}
```

**sidebarmodule.js**:

```
function sidebarAdder(pages) {
    const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidenav")

    const list = document.createElement("UL")

    for(index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {

        const ul = document.createElement("LI")
        const a = document.createElement("A")

        a.setAttribute("href", "/" + pages[index])
        a.innerHTML = "" + pages[index]

        ul.appendChild(a)
        list.appendChild(ul)

    }
    sidebar.appendChild(list)
}

export function createSidebar() {

    var pages = [
        "home",
        "tradingpost"
    ]

    sidebarAdder(pages)
}
```

It should add elements to the div. But it wont do it unless I straight up use the sidebarmodule.js. I want to do it through the app.js

**EDIT**

Found the problem!

Didn't initialize index in the for loop.

**EDIT2**

And the type="module" which needed to be added

Comment: Import is asynchronous.  sidebarmodule.js won't be loaded by the time you try to call it.  Read [the documentation on import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to see how to use `.then()`

Comment: Ok so thanks for helping guys. The problem still persists. I changed the code as Archer advised, but it still won't change the html.

app.js currently:

import("./visualModules/sidebarmodule")
    .then((sidebar) => {
        sidebar.createSidebar();
    });
I also added the type="module" to the script tag but it didn't help either. I also tried putting the script tag into header, adding async/defer, but neither of those worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load your app.js in your html file, try to add:

```
<script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

That should work when you want to use ESModules. But please update us regardless :)

**Update:** 
Ok after creating a project myself using your HTML and JS, I found a few errors.

First: When using ESModules, you can't use any functions in the JS through your HTML, you will have to inject everything from the app.js.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="sidenav">
        Here be the links to other pages
    </div>
    <br>
    <footer id="footer">
        Done whenever. Copyright is mine.
    </footer>
    <script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
import { createSidebar } from './visualModules/sidebarmodule.js';

cumulator();

function cumulator() {
    createSidebar()
}
```

Notice two things: at the end of the import, since we are not using a compiler, the modules do not recognize files without their extension. So I had to add .js to sidebarmodule. Secondly, I had to invoke cumulator function within the app.js file (like I said earlier, you cannot use any module functions outside their scope. There are no global variables with ESModules).

sidebarmodule.js:

```
function sidebarAdder(pages) {
    const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidenav")

    const list = document.createElement("UL")

    for(var index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {

        const ul = document.createElement("LI")
        const a = document.createElement("A")

        a.setAttribute("href", "/" + pages[index])
        a.innerHTML = "" + pages[index]

        ul.appendChild(a)
        list.appendChild(ul)

    }
    sidebar.appendChild(list)
}

export function createSidebar() {

    var pages = [
        "home",
        "tradingpost"
    ]

    sidebarAdder(pages)
}
```

You did not declare index inside your for loop, so I just added a var.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the list still isn't loading onto the page. Did you get it to load?

Comment: Yes, it loads on my end. Could you post your HTML code?

Comment: I tried it with jsut the body you posted and it still wouldn't work. It seems to be a problem with app.js, or vscode.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`import` is asynchronous in Javascript (in a browser, not Node.js) so you're calling `createSidebar()` before the module is loaded.  You can use import to return a promise so you can execute code once it is completed.

Remove the embedded Javascript from your html, but leave the link to app.js.  Then change app.js to this...

```
import("./visualModules/sidebarmodule")
    .then((sidebar) => {
        sidebar.createSidebar();
    });
```

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)